# lidR custom grid metric returning infinite values

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to calculate the proportion of points 0.3-2.5m above ground relative to the number of ground points + all points up to 2.5m above ground using lidR `grid_metrics()`. My custom `grid_metrics()` calculation works on the lidR demo data provided with the package (`"MixedConifer.laz"`) but fails to work with the data I'm interested in using (New Brunswick, Canada LiDAR tiles).

More specifically, this code successfully produces the metric:

```r
require(lidR)
library(raster)

# read in demo file from lidR package
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package ="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile)

shrub_cover = function(z) {
  n_shrub = sum(z >= 0.3 & z <= 2.5)
  n_veg = sum(z <= 2.5)
  return(list(ratio = n_shrub/n_veg))
}

shrub_cover_metric = grid_metrics(las, ~shrub_cover(Z), res = 10)
writeRaster(shrub_cover_metric, "data/interim/shrub_cover_demo_tile.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

But this script does not... the data I'm working with can be accessed [here](https://geonb.snb.ca/downloads2/lidar/2018/snb/aoi1/laz/nb_2018_2573000_7416000.laz)

```
las <- readLAS("C:/Users/pende/Downloads/nb_2018_2573000_7416000.laz")

shrub_cover = function(z) {
  n_shrub = sum(z >= 0.3 & z <= 2.5)
  n_veg = sum(z <= 2.5)
  return(list(ratio = n_shrub/n_veg))
}

shrub_cover_metric = grid_metrics(las, ~shrub_cover(Z), res = 10)
writeRaster(shrub_cover_metric, "data/interim/shrub_cover_nb_2018_2573000_7416000.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

I've tried removing duplicate points in the `nb_2018_2573000_7416000.laz` data, but this doesn't change the output result of a raster full of -Inf data.

What is causing this issue? The `grid_metrics()` function is the same...

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: There isn't an error message.. I find out that the raster is infinite by viewing it in ArcGIS. BUT.. I fixed my own problem! I forgot to normalize the points! I will submit an answer below.

Comment: That was my next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data I was working with contained raw elevation values and not heights above ground. To solve my problem, I needed to normalize my points. This is the script that is now working:

```
require(lidR)
library(raster)

las <- readLAS("C:/Users/pende/Downloads/nb_2018_2573000_7416000.laz")
nlas <- normalize_height(las, tin())

shrub_cover = function(z) {
  n_shrub = sum(z >= 0.3 & z <= 2.5)
  n_veg = sum(z <= 2.5)
  return(list(ratio = n_shrub/n_veg))
}

shrub_cover_metric = grid_metrics(nlas, ~shrub_cover(Z), res = 10)
writeRaster(shrub_cover_metric, "data/interim/shrub_cover_nb_2018_2573000_7416000.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```